# How to put multiple theme names in VSCode colorCustomization

Tags: visual-studio-code

For colour customisation of any theme in VSCode we do it like this

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "[Night Owl No Italics]": {
      "activityBar.background": "#000C1D",
      "activityBar.border": "#102a44",
      "sideBar.background": "#001122",
      "sideBar.border": "#102a44",
      "sideBar.foreground": "#8BADC1"
    },
```

How to add multiple name in the theme may be like `[Night Owl, Night Owl No Italics]` (This doesn't work). I don't want to repeat and define the same properties twice for two different themes. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Coming in vscode v1.59:

> There is new syntax to customize multiple themes at once:
>
> ````
>     "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
>         "[Abyss][Red]": {
>             "activityBar.background": "#ff0000"
>         },
>         "[Monokai*]": {
>             "activityBar.background": "#ff0000"
>         }
>     } ```
> ````

> Multiple themes can be listed as well as the * wildcard character can be used at the beginning and the end of the name.

- from https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_59.md#extended-theme-customisation-syntax

Answer (score 2):

This is not supported as of VS Code 1.33. You have to either:

- Duplicate the color customization for each theme
- Set the color customization globally so that it applies to all themes

Please [file a feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/new?template=feature_request.md) if you would to see your proposal supported